# How to let jQuery .load function parse blade template of laravel 4?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

1.) How would I let laravel 4 parse my external php file called by jQuery's .load?

I have this code from a separate php file named phpFile.php:

> > > `{{Form::label('nameOfCompany_FI','Name of Company',array('class'=>'control-label'))}}`

loading that php file inside a div element of my index page through a jQuery function call .load then fails to parse it as a **label** tag

`$('div').load('/getPhpFile');`

then div becomes:

`{{Form::label('nameOfCompany_FI','Name of Company',array('class'=>'control-label'))}}`

;supposedly:

`<label class="control-label" for='namOfCompany_FI'>Name Of Company</label>`

p.s: my laravel controller fn getPhpFile = `return View::make('partials/phpFile');`

Comment: rename `phpFile.php` to `phpFile.blade.php`

Comment: @itachi yep!, missed that one